# Finding the label preceding the longest line in a file

Tags: python, string

I have a file that follows a format of

```
_line 1
this is a string on a line
_line 2
this is another string
_line 3
short line
```

I am trying to write some Python code to get me the _line X label of the string below it that has the longest string length. Can you help me fix my code please? Here is what I have so far.

```
f = open('test.txt', 'r')
print f

read="null"
top_read_line_length="0"
topreadline="null"
for line in f:
    checkifread=line.find('line')
    if checkifread==1:
        print "Read label found"
        #means we are on a read line
        currentread=line
    else:
        #We are on a sequence line for currentread.
        currentlength=len(line)
        print currentlength
    print top_read_line_length

    if int(top_read_line_length) < int(currentlength):
        print topreadline
        topreadline=currentread#now topreadline label is the "_line" string
        topreadlinelength=int(currentlength)
        print topreadline

        #go to next line

print "Done"
print "Longest line is...."
print topreadline
```

Comment: Is this your actual code?  Because you have some inconsistent variable names, and the line `checkifread=line.find('line')` will find any line with the string `'line'` in it, including the 2nd line in your example input.

Comment: @brc: He does check to make sure that `line` started at position 1, so false positives are less likely.

Comment: The solutions from wim and ignas match your requirements, while mine addresses the errors in your code.  Don't forget to accept one.

Answer (score 8):

If all you wanted were the longest line in the file (like the question title says), then this one is shockingly simple in modern Python:

```
>>> max(open('test.txt'), key=len)
```

Comment: That just finds the length of the longest line, not the "label" that precedes it as the question is looking for.

Comment: @David what are you talking about?  It finds the line with the longest length.

Comment: @wim Look at what he wants. He wants the line proceeding the longest line.

Comment: @wim: true, I misspoke (miswrote, I guess). But still the point is that it only gets the longest line, whereas the OP wants to find the label prior to the longest line. For that you'd need something more like `max(zip(*[open(filename)]*2), key=lambda x: len(x[1]))[0]`, although a cute one-liner doesn't really help Brian understand why his code isn't working.

Comment: @wim read descrption of the initial problem carefully. Author has a file which consists of pairs of strings. First string from a pair is a label. He wants to find longest string among set of second lines from all these pairs and output corresponding label

Comment: The answer to the actual problem is shown below.  This has the answer to the problem as stated in the subject head, an answer that will have more value to readers other than the OP.

Comment: How will you close the file handle?

Comment: @sprezzatura I believe `close()` is called implicitly when the returned file object is no longer referenced and deallocated.

Comment: Shawn, that is correct.  CPython uses reference counting and close the file for you as soon as max() is done.  In PyPy, that garbage collector does the work at a time of its choosing or when the script ends.  In the case of this example, the script is only uses one file and then ends upon printing its result.  All versions of Python will have closed the file before exiting.

Answer (score 8):

To fetch the label of the longest line, build a mapping of labels to line-lengths

In your sample dataset, it looks like labels startwith "_line " and the corresponding line immediately follows:

```
label2linelength = {}
for line in open('test.txt'):
    if line.startswith('_line '):
        label = line
    else:
        label2linelength[label] = len(line)
    lastline = line
print max(label2linelength.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1])
```

Comment: Why two separate answers? (with the first not answering the question)

Comment: The first answers the question in the subject head (finding the length of the longest line in a file).  That is a general purpose answer that has a certain magic about it.   The second answer addresses the more mundane homework-style problem stated in the body of request.  That one is unlikely to  be of general use, so there are two answers.

Comment: I can see the difference, I just don't see why they have to be in separate answers.

Comment: I've been on stackoverflow for just a couple days and am still figuring it out.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think this answer fails for the case where all "content" lines are shorter that the "label" lines.

Comment: Both are great answers to different questions, and the problem with splitting up the answer - one to answer the title and another to answer the actual question - is that the title may eventually get edited to match the question and you're left with a hanging question. BTW, welcome to SO!

Comment: Raymond, so glad to see you here. great answer, by the way, what about use key=itemgetter(1) .

Comment: Every other line is a label, not every line.

Answer (score 3):

That is easy to achieve:

```
data = open('test.txt').readlines()
max_line_pos = data.index(max(data, key=len))
prev_line = data[max_line_pos-1]
print prev_line
```

Comment: Fails when a label is the longest line.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do something like:

```
label = None
maxlen = 0
maxstr = ''
maxlabel = None
with open('f.txt') as f:
  for line in f:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line.startswith('_line'):
      label = line
    elif len(line) > maxlen:
      maxlen = len(line)
      maxstr = line
      maxlabel = label
print maxlabel, maxstr
```

It's a little bit more generic than the problem statement in that it allows multiple lines of text per label.

Comment: Like. Would it be possible to use `for line in file(...)` instead of `with` + `for` here?

Comment: From `file.__doc__`: The preferred way to open a file is with the builtin open() function.

Comment: Actual value lines cannot start with '_line' with this solution.

Answer (score 2):

I'd elaborate on Raymond's answer; if grouper() were available in the standard lib this answer would be quite close to a oneliner again; unluckily it isn't, grouper is only defined in [itertools examples.](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html)

I think you'd prefer this version since it's functional. I didn't test its performance, but at least I'm not opening the file and seeking twice nor I'm keeping the whole contents in memory.

```
from itertools import izip_longest
def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

max( grouper(2, open("test.txt")), key=lambda x:len(x[1]))[0]
```

Comment: `key` should be using the length -- currently your solution returns `_line 2` when it should be `_line 1`.

Comment: Ethan: well spotted, it was in fact a copy-and-paste glitch - I pasted an old version of the file which contained the error. BTW the approach works, I'm editing it right now to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Another concise variant:

```
from itertools import imap, izip
from operator import itemgetter
with open("a.py") as f:
    res = max(izip(f, imap(len, f)), key=itemgetter(1))[0]
```

This treats every other line as a label.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my one.  It works where a few of the other answers here would fail, e.g. an input file like

```
_line 1
abc
_line 2
defg
_line 3
hij
```

But it does rely on the format of the file being just how you said it was.

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
  spam = f.readlines()

labels = spam[0::2]
lines = spam[1::2]

d = dict(zip(labels, lines))

longest_lines_label = max(d, key=lambda x: len(d[x]))

print "Longest line is...."
print longest_lines_label, d[longest_lines_label]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure the data is correct and don't need any error handling this should do the job:

```
lines = open('test.txt', 'r').readlines()
print max([(len(lines[i+1]), lines[i])
           for i in xrange(0, len(lines), 2)])[1].strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an `awk` program that will do it:

```
BEGIN { best=""; best_length=0; current=""; }
/^_/ { current=$0; }
/^[^_]/ { if(length($0) > best_length) { best=current; best_length=length($0); }}
END { print "Longest line: "best" with length: "best_length }
```

(I like it better than the following `python` version, which more closely answers your question....)

```
best = ""
best_length = 0
current = ""
for line in f:  #( assumes f = open(...) from your code )
  if line[:5] == '_line':
    current = line.strip()
    continue
  else:
    if len(line) > best_length:
      best = current
      best_length = len(line.strip())
print "Longest line is: %s with length: %d" % (best,best_length)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly short, and works even if you have multiple lines of text after each label

```
content = list(open("test.txt"))
longest = content.index(max(content, key=len))
label = [ x for x in content[0:longest] if x.startswith("_line") ][-1]
print label.replace("_line ","")
```

Comment: Actual value lines cannot start with '_line' with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

And here's yet another way:

```
import re, mmap

with open("test.txt", "rb") as f:
    mm = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, mmap.MAP_PRIVATE, mmap.PROT_READ)
    print max(re.finditer(r'_line (\d+)\n(.*)', mm),
              key=lambda m: len(m.group(2))).group(1)
```

Comment: I'll take that as a compliment :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code, fixed:

```
f = open('test.txt', 'r')
print f

read = None
top_read_line_length = 0
topreadline = None
currentlength = 0
label_line = True
for line in f:  
    if label_line:
        label_line = False
        print "label line", line
        #means we are on a read line
        currentread = line
    else:
        label_line = True
        #We are on a sequence line for currentread.
        currentlength = len(line)
        print 'cl', currentlength
    print top_read_line_length

    if top_read_line_length < currentlength:
        print 'trl', topreadline
        topreadline = currentread #now topreadline label is the "_line" string
        top_read_line_length = currentlength
        print 'trl', topreadline

        #go to next line

print "Done"
print "Longest line is...."
print topreadline
```

I added a `label_line` boolean to switch back and forth between lable-lines and data-lines, but the important pieces were:

- put enough info on your print lines to see what's going on; and
- be consistent with your variable names

The problem was in the last `if` suite -- you were checking `top_read_line_length` but were setting `topreadlinelength` (no underscores).